# Microsoft Word Plugin for Web Mail

Tags: microsoft-word, plugins

I am 100% positive that I recently saw on the Internet a new plugin for MS Word which allowed the user to choose a Web Mail service such as Gmail or Ymail instead of Outlook or Live.  Am I totally losing my sanity, and "it's just my 'magination runnin' away with me"?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**[Affixa](http://www.affixa.com/)** makes your webmail account part of Windows.

> Affixa allows you to use you web mail
>   service from within Windows just as if
>   it were a desktop email client.
>
> If you right click on any file and
>   select "Send to mail recipient" then
>   Affixa automatically creates an email
>   in your webmail account drafts folder
>   with the file attached. You can then
>   open that mail and send it whoever you
>   want.
>
> If you have several attachments you
>   can create a "collection" to be
>   emailed.  If the attachment is too
>   large for your web mail service Affixa
>   offers to deliver the attachments via
>   the free Drop.io web service.

*Affixa is free of charge for personal use.*

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of accelerators for IE8.